# PHP: Using str_pad not working? Why?

Tags: php, string-concatenation

I have a string, its content is "24896". Now I want to add some zeros to the left, so I tried:

```
$test = str_pad($myString, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

The result is "24896" again, no zeros added to the left. Am I missing something here?

Thanks!

Comment: how many no zero you want to add?

Answer (score 14):

The second argument to `str_pad()` takes the full length of the final string; because you're passing 4 and the length of `$myString` is 5, nothing will happen.

You should choose a width that's at least one bigger than your example value, e.g.:

```
str_pad($myString, 9, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
// "000024896"
```

**Update**

This might be obvious, but if you always want 4 zeros in front of whatever `$myString` is:

```
'0000' . $myString;
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're padding it to length 4, and your string `24896` is 5 characters long, hence it doesn't need to pad anything as it's already more than 4 characters long.

The second parameter in the `str_pad` function is the new length of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$myString = "24896" ;
$test = str_pad($myString, strlen($myString) + 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo $test;
```

Output

```
000024896
```

Comment: You mean `'0000' . $myString` surely? :)

Comment: yeah .. better still `str_pad($myString, $max, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);`

Comment: Perhaps if you would define what `$max` is? :)

Comment: `$max` maximum let of string to be displayed `9` in this case

Answer (score 1):

Just make the pad first and attach it, presuming you don't know how long it is. No need to calculate the length of the original string:

```
$x = 4;
$pad = str_pad('', $x, '0');
$test = $pad.$myString;
```

Or better

```
 $x = 4;
 $test = str_pad('', $x, '0').$myString;
```

Answer (score 0):

The length you specified in the str_function is less than the input string read documentation properly 
try this it will work for you

Your String is 5 character
e.g $myString=24896;
Now you want to add 5 zero to the left

then your length will be you string + 5 the actual is 5+5=10;

Now pass this to the function your function will be like this

$test = str_pad($myString, 10, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

echo $test;

OUTPUT:
0000024896

Answer (score 0):

how many no zero you want to add? no zeros added because padding length is smaller than your given $myString length.

Please try this one

```
$number = 24896; 
$number = sprintf('%06d', $number); 
echo $number;
```

or use this one

```
$number = 24896;
$number = str_pad($number, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);//here 6 is padding length
echo $number;
```

output

```
024896
```